# Use specified quantifier in grep to retrieve satisfied vocabulary

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I try to grab words from a file:

```
$ grep -o '\*\*[^*]*\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md | grep -v -e "Origin" -e "Etymology"
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
**the state of feeling nervous or worried that sth bad is going to happen**
**a worry or fear about sth**
**a strong feeling of wanting to do sth or of wanting sth to happen**
```

The result I intend is to get only words:

```
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
```

Refactored code with specified quatifiers `{,20}`:

```
$ grep -E -o '\*\*[^*]{,20}\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md
```

Unfortunately, it returns nothing.

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: Another option may be to add (space) to your exclusion list, next to the `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BSD grep, see `man 7 re_format` for details of the regular expressions supported. In particular, it says:

```
 A bound is `{' followed by an unsigned decimal integer, possibly followed
 by `,' possibly followed by another unsigned decimal integer, always fol-
 lowed by `}'.  The integers must lie between 0 and RE_DUP_MAX (255=)
 inclusive, and if there are two of them, the first may not exceed the
 second.
```

Only the second number can be omitted; the first *has* to be given.

With that fix:

```
$ /usr/bin/grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
$ /usr/bin/grep -Eo '\*\*[^*]{0,20}\*\*' foo
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
```